# Annoying error with stats models.api OLS after upgrading to Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a statistical Python program that was working fine until a few days ago when I upgraded to Mac OS Mavericks.  Pursuant to this upgrade I figured out I had to reinstall MySQL and some libraries.  Anyways, I had downloaded numpy/scipy/statsmodels in order to use their Ordinary Least Squares formula within Python-Pandas.

So now post upgrade, I'm getting an error on this line:

```
regressionoutput = sm.OLS(y,x, missing='drop').fit()
```

Error given -

> `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing'`

However, in the OLS annotation, the keyword 'missing' is one of the main parameters.  Also this was working previously with statsmodels.  Also, if I remove the argument, then the NaNs kill the program and lead to a lot more errors.

Any ideas why I'm getting the `unexpected keyword` error?

Comment: You can check which version of statsmodels you have in your working python, `statsmodels.__version__` to see whether you don't have now an older version that doesn't have `missing`. I don't see any other possible explanation.

Comment: Thanks for reading this and the help.  It turns out that one of the dependencies (Patsy) hadn't been updated via Anaconda and Python/statsmodels was being coy that that was the reason.  I re-updated all libraries and dependencies today and Statsmodels is working fine.